# ASP GridView List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

If I wanted to add a new item to a `<List>` with the Data key name from a gridview how would I go about doing it?

Example.

```
List<myClass> myList  = new List<myClass>();

myList.add(new myClass(*//The value of the data key name that has been clicked*));
```

A user might click on another item so it would be repeated etc etc.

Comment: What event are you wanting to do this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Brian: Check it out:

```
    protected void dataGridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {   
        if(myList == null)        
          myList = new List<myClass>();
        foreach (object keys in dataGridView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values)
        {
            myList.Add(keys);
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in rowSelected, and get the data key in a form of:

```
protected void Gridview_SelectedIndexChanged(..)
{
   GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;
  var key = this.gvw.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
}
```

Forget the exact syntax, but this is essentially what you do.